# A interesting inequality involving omega function that might be true

Tags: number-theory

I want to prove the following inequality as a curiousity, I checked small values and realize that it might be true.
So let, $\omega(n)=$number of Primes divinding $n$ if $a\leq 1$ consider $\omega(a)=0$
Let $\mathbb{P}$=Set of all prime numbers.
Here is the question.

Is it true that,
$$(\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}_{\leq 2n}} \omega(2n-2-p))>(\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}_{\leq 2n}} \omega(2n-p))-1$$

Till $60$ I checked few values by hand and I realised it's true, However I need this to be true for $n>99$
Then I observed the following fact from the definition of $$\omega(n)=\sum_{p|n} 1=\sum_{p\in \mathbb{P}}([\frac{n}{p}]-[\frac{n-1}{p}])$$
$[.]$=G.I.F

By plugging my deduduced $\omega(n)$ in my question I tried many apprroach but I failed.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is going to be one of those things where small numbers hide reality. $\omega(n) \le 3$ for $n<210$. With larger numbers you're more likely to get wild swings. That said, I get counterexamples starting at $n=4$, so I wonder if you were calculating what you've actually written? For $n=4$, the LHS is $\omega(4)+\omega(3) = 1+1=2$, and the RHS is $\omega(6)+\omega(5)+\omega(3)-1 = 2+1+1-1 = 3$. Is that not your intended calculation?